# How can I map an array of coordinates into React Native Maps Markers?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, mapping, react-native-maps

I want to map an array of geographical coordinates into React Native Maps Markers (i.e. pins). The array of data I am mapping through has about 100 values. Thus, I am expecting 97 markers to render (the API data isn't perfect). However, 0 markers appear on the Google map. Here is my code:

```
mapDataToMarkers() {
const searchData = this.props.data;
return (
  <MapView style={styles.mapStyle} mapType={"mutedStandard"}>
    {searchData.map((host, i) => {
        if (host.location.latitude && host.location.longitude) {
          console.log("TEST", host.location.latitude);
          <Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: host.location.latitude,
              longitude: host.location.longitude
            }}
            title={host.name}
            pinColor={"#ffd1dc"}
          />;
        }
      })}
  </MapView>
);
```

The `console.log()` produces 97 latitudes in my terminal, so I know the data is correct and the code is reachable. I've already tried passing an object called *latlng* to the `coordinate` prop as the documentation suggests, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I never figured this would be an issue in the first place.

[Click for React-Native-Maps Documentation](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't return anything in the map function, try this:

```
<MapView style={styles.mapStyle} mapType={"mutedStandard"}>
    {searchData.map((host, i) => {
        if (host.location.latitude && host.location.longitude) {
          console.log("TEST", host.location.latitude);
         return(<Marker
            key={i}
            coordinate={{
              latitude: host.location.latitude,
              longitude: host.location.longitude
            }}
            title={host.name}
            pinColor={"#ffd1dc"}
          />)
        }
      })}
  </MapView>
```

you can see it [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thank you @Lenoarod, it worked! I will make this the accepted answer as soon as Stack Overflow allows.